# Using multiple list in count condition to create resource in Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am using the following condition for creating the follwoing resource in Terraform

```
resource "google_bigquery_dataset_access" "access" {
  count         = contains(var.bq_access, "viewer") ? length(var.bigquery_datasets) : 0
  project       = "test-project"
  dataset_id    = var.bigquery_datasets[count.index].dataset_id
  role          = "roles/bigquery.dataViewer"
  user_by_email = lower(var.user_email[?])
}
```

I am trying to create multiple instances of this resource based on `length(var.bigquery_datasets)`, the problem is the `var.user_email` is a list and I want this resource to be created for all emails and for all elements of bigquery_datasets. How can I combine the following code and the code above in one resource block?

```
resource "google_bigquery_dataset_access" "access" {
  count         = contains(var.bq_access, "viewer") ? length(var.user_email) : 0
  project       = "test-project"
  dataset_id    = var.bigquery_datasets[?].dataset_id
  role          = "roles/bigquery.dataViewer"
  user_by_email = lower(var.user_email[count.index])
}
```

The length of `var.bigquery_datasets` and `var.user_email` is not the same. Any help would be appreciated. Thankyou!

UPDATE :

```
variable "user_email" {
  type        = list(any)
  description = "email addresses list"
}
```

eg definition user_email = ["email1@xyz.com", "email2@xyz.com", "email3@xyz.com"]

```
variable "bigquery_datasets" {
  type        = list(any)
  description = "datasets list"
}
```

eg definition bigquery_datasets = ["datasetid1", "datasetid2", "datasetid3", "datasetid4", "datasetid5"]

Comment: Can you add those two variables to the question as well? My first answer is that it can't be done unless `user_email` and `bigquery_datasets` are of the same length.

Comment: @MarkoE Added the variable definitions, I also spent a lot of time thinking about it but failed to find a way

Comment: And is there any other correlation between the two? E.g., should all the emails be allowed to access all the datasets?

Comment: @MarkoE Yes thats correct , all the emails should be able to access all the datasets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that `setproduct` would solve your issue:

```
locals {
  emails_datasets = setproduct(var.user_email, var.bigquery_datasets)
}

resource "google_bigquery_dataset_access" "access" {
  count         = contains(var.bq_access, "viewer") ? length(local.emails_datasets) : 0
  project       = "test-project"
  dataset_id    = local.emails_datasets[count.index][1]
  role          = "roles/bigquery.dataViewer"
  user_by_email = lower(local.emails_datasets[count.index][0])
}
```

Comment: Thanks I just found the setproduct function of Terraform and also testing it myself. Thanks for the answer. Much appreciated

Comment: Another way of dealing this situation is to create a GCP group with the individual emails and use "group_by_email" parameter instead of "user_by_email"